# How to increase width of the walls?

Tags: properties, scale, dimensions

So I am beginner to blender. I want to make an object like swimming pool.
I made a cube and deleted one face. Now I have no idea how to increase width of the walls. I tried to extrude each face, but now I have a hole in connections between walls. I could not find other opportunities to make such changes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways. This is one of them (maybe not the best, but should be easy to follow):

1. Create a cube
2. Resize the cube to match the size of the pool ( <kbd>s</kbd> )
3. Apply your object's scale( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> > *Scale*)
4. Go to edit mode (<kbd>TAB</kbd>)
5. Press <kbd>3</kbd> to switch to "face selection"
6. Select top face
7. Inset the face <kbd>i</kbd>
8. Select the inner face and extrude vertically with <kbd>e</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> (so you can create the "hole" in the swimming pool
9. If you want to change the width of the walls you can select inner faces (check screenshot) and resize them in both X and Y to get your result ( <kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, i feel myself so stupid now, that I did not try in other direction :D But If I am going to follow your suggestion, is it possible to get rid of the holes in connection, so that it looks solid, without any separations?

Comment: You should have no holes in connection. 
Can you post a screenshot of your actual situation?

Comment: thank you, I understood what I did wrongly